# Can a React Native or NativeBase Picker have Items which include images?

Tags: react-native, drop-down-menu, icons, picker, native-base

I'm new to smartphone programming and have joined a project using React Native and NativeBase.

I'd like to include an image/icon in each Item in a Picker, which doesn't seem like an exotic concept, but it doesn't seem to be supported and I can't find anyone discussing doing it on SO or by Googling.

I've tried a couple ways of adding things inside the `<Picker.Item>` and `</Picker.Item>` but anything put there seems to simply be ignored.

Is it possible or is there a different approach to do what I want using these frameworks?

Comment: do you mean something like modal dropdown? https://github.com/sohobloo/react-native-modal-dropdown

Comment: @GaneshCauda: That looks exactly like what I was looking for if you want to submit it as an answer.

Comment: sure glad to do it :), please let me know if you have trouble in implementing this

Comment: In my case the images were flags and I was able to use Unicode emoji flags as an alternative so I won't have to implement it just yet after all (-:

Comment: hmmm seems like a little bit advance for me, please let me know if you able to achieve your goal. I would like to know it as well :), good luck with the project

Comment: let me know how to render base64 string in that renderRow . Tnx.                          https://github.com/sohobloo/react-native-modal-dropdown/issues/180

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try this package

https://github.com/sohobloo/react-native-modal-dropdown

the complete example you can check here

https://github.com/sohobloo/react-native-modal-dropdown/blob/master/example/index.js

the use is something like this

```
_dropdown_2_renderRow(rowData, rowID, highlighted) {
let icon = highlighted ? require('./images/heart.png') : require('./images/flower.png');
let evenRow = rowID % 2;
return (
  <TouchableHighlight underlayColor='cornflowerblue'>
    <View style={[styles.dropdown_2_row, {backgroundColor: evenRow ? 'lemonchiffon' : 'white'}]}>
      <Image style={styles.dropdown_2_image}
             mode='stretch'
             source={icon}
      />
      <Text style={[styles.dropdown_2_row_text, highlighted && {color: 'mediumaquamarine'}]}>
        {`${rowData.name} (${rowData.age})`}
      </Text>
    </View>
  </TouchableHighlight>
);
}
```

the end product example is look like this :

[image]

all copyrights belongs to :
https://github.com/sohobloo

Comment: I believe you can use any react-native component for the row component, and default <Image/> component supposed to be able to load base64 sources

Comment: let me know how to render base64 string in that renderRow . Tnx.          github.com/sohobloo/react-native-modal-dropdown/issues/180                        .Please check this