# How do I add icon/images to my picker items in React Native?

Tags: react-native, icons, picker

I have a Picker component with two language choices: French and Korean.  I would like to add an icon/picture of a flag next to each Text Component.  Something that would like something like this: [image]

I don't see anything about adding an icon in the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/picker.html) Other than installing something like react-native-modal-dropdown is there a way that this can be done? I would like to avoid installing any additional stuff.

Comment: I think this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48478120/can-not-set-image-as-picker-item-label-in-android) answers your question.He renders the icon in Picker.Item label prop but he is using the picker component from NativeBase.Don't know if this works on default RN picker as well.

Answer (score 13):

Since i was looking for a solution myself, i tried the solution that i referenced in my previous comment but i couldn't make it work for the default RN picker.What i found instead, is that you can use Unicode emojis (thanks to a comment by [hippietrail](https://stackoverflow.com/users/527702/hippietrail) found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45901897/can-a-react-native-or-nativebase-picker-have-items-which-include-images?rq=1)). So just copy the flag emoji you want from somewhere (i used [emojipedia](https://emojipedia.org/flag-for-south-korea/)) and put it inside the label prop.Here is a very simple example of how this works

```
export default class App extends Component {
  state = {
        language: ''
  };

   render() {
     return (
       <View style={styles.container}>
           <Picker
              selectedValue={this.state.language}
              style={{ height: 50, width: 200 }}
              onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({language: itemValue})}>
              <Picker.Item label="  South Korea" value="ko" />
              <Picker.Item label="  France" value="fr" />

          </Picker>
       </View>
     );
   }
 }

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
});
```

where  and  are the unicode emojis i copied from emojipedia.And this is how it looks like in [Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4c7rS.png) (looks similar in iOS)

Comment: well, very nice way to workaround a RN limitation :)