# Can not set <Image> as Picker.Item label in Android

Tags: android, react-native, picker

For my react-native app, I need Image+Text in `label` of `Picker.Item` like in picture below.

[image]

Everything okay in IOS but on Android I get an error.

Here is my Picker Component code.

```
<Picker style={{width: 100, height: '100%', marginLeft: 5}}
        selectedValue={this.state.selectedCountry}
        onValueChange={(value)=>this.onCodeChanged(value)}>
    <Picker.Item label={<Text style={{alignItems: 'center', flexDirection: 'row'}}>
        <Thumbnail square style={{width: 30, height: 20, marginTop: 5}} source={require('../assets/+90.png')}/> +90</Text>} value="+90"/>
    <Picker.Item label={<Text style={{alignItems: 'center', flexDirection: 'row'}}>
        <Thumbnail square style={{width: 30, height: 20, marginTop: 5}} source={require('../assets/+44.png')}/> +44</Text>} value="+44"/>
    <Picker.Item label={<Text style={{alignItems: 'center', flexDirection: 'row'}}>
        <Thumbnail square style={{width: 30, height: 20, marginTop: 5}} source={require('../assets/+1.png')}/> +1</Text>} value="+1"/>
</Picker>
```

here is the error screen I get on Android

[image]

I got stuck here for 24 hours, please help me.

Here is the whole file - Leads.JS

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Dimensions, AsyncStorage,View,Image, TextInput} from 'react-native';
import {Container, Form, H3, Footer, Button, Icon, Text, Body, Spinner, Item, Left, Right, Input, Thumbnail,Picker,Label} from 'native-base';
import {Actions} from 'react-native-router-flux';
import Header from './commonComponents/CustomHeader'

const {width, height} = Dimensions.get("window"),
    vw = width / 100
vh = height / 100

export default class Leads extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        console.log("in constructor");
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            selectedCountry: '+44',
            selectedCountryImage: '+44.png',
            fullName: 'Terry',
            placeHolder: 'full name',
            phone: '45245421'
        };
    };


    onCodeChanged(value)
    {
        this.setState({selectedCountry: value},()=>this.setImage());

    }

    setImage()
    {
        imgName = '../assets/' + this.state.selectedCountry + '.png';
        this.setState({selectedCountryImage: imgName},()=>console.log("Image: ",this.state.selectedCountryImage,"\nCountry: ", this.state.selectedCountry));
    }


    render()
    {

        const styles = {
            container: {
                alignItems: 'center'
            }
        }

        return(
            <Container>
                <Header title={"Leads"}/>
                <View style={{width: width-40, marginLeft: 20, marginRight: 20, height: height-140, marginTop: 20,flexDirection: 'column'}}>

                    <View style={{backgroundColor: '#d7d7d7', width: '100%', height: 50, justifyContent: 'center', marginTop: 30}}>
                        <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold', marginLeft: 10}}>Lead Info</Text>
                    </View>

                    <Text style={{fontWeight: 'bold', color: '#d7d7d7',width: '100%', marginTop: 20}}>Full Name</Text>
                    <View style={{height: 50, width: '100%', borderBottomColor: '#d7d7d7', borderBottomWidth: 1, flexDirection: 'column'}}>
                        {/*<Item style={{flexDirection: 'column',justifyContent: 'space-between'}} stackedLabel>*/}

                        {/*<Input placeholderTextColor="rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6)" placeholder={this.state.placeHolder} textColor='red' value={this.state.fullName} style={{marginTop: 20,color: "black"}} onChangeText={fullName => this.setState({fullName})}/>*/}
                        <Input style={{height: '60%',width: '100%', color: 'red'}} value={this.state.fullName} onChangeText={fullName => this.setState({fullName})}/>
                        {/*</Item>*/}
                    </View>


                    <View style={{height: 40, marginTop: 20}}>

                        <Label style={{fontWeight: 'bold', color: '#d7d7d7'}}>Phone</Label>
                        <View style={{flexDirection: 'row',width: '100%',borderWidth: 1, borderColor: '#d7d7d7', height: 40}}>
                            <View style={{flexDirection: 'row',width: '30%', height: '100%' ,backgroundColor: '#d7d7d7', alignItems: 'center'}}>
                                <Picker style={{width: 100, height: '100%', marginLeft: 5}}
                                        selectedValue={this.state.selectedCountry}
                                        onValueChange={(value)=>this.onCodeChanged(value)}>
                                    <Picker.Item label={<Text style={{alignItems: 'center', flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                                        <Thumbnail square style={{width: 30, height: 20, marginTop: 5}} source={require('../assets/+90.png')}/> +90</Text>} value="+90"/>
                                    <Picker.Item label={<Text style={{alignItems: 'center', flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                                        <Thumbnail square style={{width: 30, height: 20, marginTop: 5}} source={require('../assets/+44.png')}/> +44</Text>} value="+44"/>
                                    <Picker.Item label={<Text style={{alignItems: 'center', flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                                        <Thumbnail square style={{width: 30, height: 20, marginTop: 5}} source={require('../assets/+1.png')}/> +1</Text>} value="+1"/>
                                </Picker>
                            </View>
                            <Input keyboardType={'numeric'} style={{width: '70%', height: '100%'}} value={this.state.phone} onChangeText={(value)=>this.setState({phone: value},()=>console.log("Phone State: ", this.state.phone))}/>
                        </View>

                    </View>

                    <View style={{ width: '100%', borderBottomColor: '#d7d7d7', borderBottomWidth: 1, flexDirection: 'column',marginTop: 30}}>
                        {/*<Item style={{flexDirection: 'column',justifyContent: 'space-between'}} stackedLabel>*/}
                        <Label style={{fontWeight: 'bold', color: '#d7d7d7'}}>Note</Label>
                        {/*<Input placeholderTextColor="rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6)" placeholder={this.state.placeHolder} textColor='red' value={this.state.fullName} style={{marginTop: 20,color: "black"}} onChangeText={fullName => this.setState({fullName})}/>*/}
                        <Input style={{marginTop: 10}}/>
                        {/*</Item>*/}
                    </View>


                    <Button style={{backgroundColor: '#ff5a00', justifyContent: 'center', width: '100%', height: height/15, marginTop: 20}}>
                        <Text>Added</Text>
                    </Button>


                    <Button style={{backgroundColor: '#ff5a00', justifyContent: 'center', width: '100%', height: height/15, marginTop: 20}}>
                        <Text>Edit</Text>
                    </Button>
                </View>

            </Container>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: This actually looks like a bug in RN when merging the styles. Can you post your entire code? The styles specially.

Comment: @sfratini I edited the question and added the whole file.

Comment: You are using the styles incorrectly. See my answer

Answer (score 0):

After seeing your complete code, I can see you are using the components from NativeBase. If you see the code, it is trying to merge styles and send that to the react native picker.

By looking at the documentation, you are actually setting the styles and I am guessing the native base code is adding another styles which RN does not like.

So, take a look at this documentation, and instead of using the style prop, use the ones provided by the framework:

https://docs.nativebase.io/Components.html#picker-def-headref

See that they have headerStyle, itemStyle, itemTextStyle and textStyle.

Comment: Thanks, man. But maybe it is not related with style prop. Because, as I know, in android platform picker does not work without width. When I removed style prop, it does not show up in android. 
Also, it still works properly when I set label of picker.item to usual string with quotes, for example like "label". It seems picker does not work on android when I set image component to label of picker.item

Comment: The error you are facing is in the mapPropsToStyles function. I looked the code. The other error is that the RN Picker cannot stringify cyclc structures. Meaning that somehow that function is creating a cyclic style. Just don't use the style prop in the picker and pickerItem and use the props form NativeBase. Have you tried that?

Comment: Yeap. When I remove style prop, picker does not work in android emulator. As I understood, we need to add width prop of style to picker in order to use it in android.

Comment: But did you use the specific style props that the native base picker have? See the docs

Comment: I tried all of them. itemStyle, itemTextStyle, headerStyle. But nothing changed. Same result: When I keep style prop, I get the error screen above and when I remove style prop, I do not get error but my picker component is unresponsive, does not work.

Answer (score 0):

**Text** on Android does not allow nested views. Only nested **Text**s are allowed (they convert to Spans).
See this link: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text.html